# Gradle version not supported after Android Studio update

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am running on Windows 10.

I just updated the Android studio to 3.6, and my app is no longer syncing. I'm getting 3 separate responses for the failure

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 5.4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\**redacted**\**redacted**\Documents\Android Studio\app\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
>
> ERROR: Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 5.4.1.
>
> Please fix the project's Gradle settings.

Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project **(Appears as an un-clickable link for me)**

Open Gradle wrapper properties **(Appears as an un-clickable link for me)**

Gradle settings **(Appears as an un-clickable link for me)***

Being smart as I am, I checked my gradle-wrapper properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

In the project structure, the Gradle version is also correct, 5.6.4.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio.

I have also tried running the program on a different machine.

I created a brand new (working!) project to compare the gradle-wrapper properties file and everything matches.

Please help me out if you can.

Comment: Can you check what is the gradle version in build.gradle?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update as to how I resolved the situation. I started a brand new project, and copied over all the Kotlin and XML code. I'm still not sure what went wrong.

Comment: i just update my android studio to android 4 .then show this kind of error.so i applied your approach.I think it will be Android studio automatically configure downloading latest gradle file .my error was (Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 6.0.1.)

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the project directory and re-imported the project, and it worked. Then I changed it back to the old name and it continued working. Magic!

P.S.
BTW I also deleted all the .iml files .idea .gradle files gradle gradlew gradlew.bat files also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it just ignores what is in gradle-wrapper.properties. After a week of frustration and trying dozens of different solutions that didn't solve it...

1. Create a new 3.6.1 dummy project and Gradle Sync to force download of the new Gradle distribution.
2. Then in *File -> Settings -> Gradle*, set *Use Gradle from* to *Specified location* and set the full path of where your gradle is (e.g. `C:\Users\Duncan\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.4-all\ankdp27end7byghfw1q2sw75f\gradle-5.6.4`). And finally it works again!
3. Then you can delete the new dummy project.

Why is Android Studio / Gradle so ridiculously overcomplicated and unreliable ? Every upgrade is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice of these awesome Flutter error messages and simply replaced in my project's file `<project>/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` the line `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip` by `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip` (thereby only changing the version of the employed gradle module).

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade (Increase) the build.gradle version
[image]